# Sent the address of image with bootstrap in a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

i have this problem.
With this form i try to sent the address of image in a MySQL database

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Inserisci un immagine con la facciata della struttura</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
          <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="imgInp">
        </div>
        <img src='/project' id='img-upload' name='img-upload'/>
  </div>
```

in my php file i have this code

```
$durlimage = file_get_contents($_POST["imgInp"]);
echo '<br>'.$durlimage.'<br>';
```

I have this error

> Warning: file_get_contents(Schermata del 2018-07-11 11.20.34.png):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/newpoi.php on line 24

Why the address of the image doesn't show?

Comment: You can't just use `file_get_contents` to upload a file onto your server. Check any of the many tutorials online, like https://w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. In essence you have to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: you are looking for a `string` but you have a `file`